# Find for which parameter a there is Lyapunov/Asymptotic Stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory

this is a problem from one of the former exams from ordinary differential equations: as stated in topic, find for which parameters a the solution (0,0) is asymptotically and lapunov stable.

$$ x'= (2a+1)x- \frac{y}{y+1}$$
$$ y'= sinx-(a+1)y$$
My idea is to reduce it by taylor expansion , as i have done it

$$x'= (2a+1)x-y+y^2$$
$$y'= x-x^3-(a+1)y$$
Now we get rid of the higher degree expressions to use a theorem, we get 
$$x'= (2a+1)x-y$$
$$y'= x-(a+1)y$$
and we calculate the soultions of its characteristic polynomial, their real part has to be below zero to make the solution stable and after calculating it we get
that for $$ -3/2<a<0$$ it is asomptytically stable 
My question is, is it even correct?! and what can I do for others a

Comment: According to my calculations (and to Mathematica, too), the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2-a\lambda-2a^2-3a$. So, a necessary and sufficient condition for both its roots having negative real parts is $-3/2<a<0$. Next, your second display is **not** a linear system (and you have not replaced $\sin{x}$ there by its Taylor expansion, only by its two nonzero terms). Finally, the principle of linearized stability tells nothing about Lyapunov stability alone. You have to use other tools, as Lyapunov functions.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, at first I was trying to build some Lyapunov functions, which would eliminate this sinx, but it all seemed to lead to nowhere, any ideas on what form would this function take?

Comment: The "standard example" is $V(x)=x^2+y^2$, if not then one tries $V(x,y)=x^4+y^4$, and so on. But I sincerely doubt if here that could be of any help. My advice would be to try drawing a picture of the phase portrait near the original, for the "marginal" cases $a=0$ and $a=-3/2$ (to see what one should expect).

Comment: I will ask since I am not sure if I get this right, from the calculations we have made above, we get the asymptotic stability for a in (-3/2,0) and not stability for other a,  but we know nothing about Lyapunov stability

Comment: From the pictures I have just posted it would rather follow that for $a=0$ and $a=-3/2$ the origin is unstable. For $a=-3/2$ one eigenvalue is negative and the other is zero. One could try to find a center manifold corresponding to the zero eigenvalue and look at how the flow behaves on that manifold. But this is not an easy task!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a picture of the phase portrait for $a = -3/2$, that is, for 
$$
\begin{cases}
x'= -2 x- \frac{y}{y+1}
\\
y'= \sin{x} - \frac{y}{2}.
\end{cases}
$$
[image]

The origin appears to be unstable.

For the second marginal case ($a = 0$), that is,
$$
\begin{cases}
x'=  x- \frac{y}{y+1}
\\
y'= \sin{x} - y,
\end{cases}
$$
a picture is

[image]

Again, this looks like an unstable equilibrium.

Finally, a picture of 
$$
\begin{cases}
x'=  - x- \frac{y}{y+1}
\\
y'= \sin{x}
\end{cases}
$$

[image]

(a stable focus),

and of

$$
\begin{cases}
x'=  - 1.8 \, x- \frac{y}{y+1}
\\
y'= \sin{x} + 0.4 \, y
\end{cases}
$$

[image]

(a stable node).